# Replace text in HTMLBody of an email template

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, outlook, html-email

I have been using the below code for years to generate communications. I am adapting it to new requirements.

The code grabs data from Sharepoint/MS Teams to filter then copy into a new tab. The code calls an email template that contains placeholders in multiple tables which includes a banner. By using strings it replaces the value of cells with the placeholder.

The data has bullet points and is in paragraphs. However when the email is generated, it has the data in one block as one continuous line.

I tried inserting line breaks but without success.

My latest iteration is to use a replace function, after the loop through the string arrays.

```vb
.HTMLBody = replace(.htmlBody, ";", "<BR>")
```

I put ";" at the end of a line when I want to go the next line.

However, whilst the `<BR>` does add the line break, it changes the font to Times New Roman and puts in a lot HTML garbage when the email is generated. I suspect is it is from the `"<BR>"`.

The odd thing is when I add a `debug.print` onto `.htmlbody` it shows the font and line breaks are correct, with or without the second replace function.

I also tried to change `"<BR>"` with `CHR(10)` and `vbnewline` and other permutations.

I have not included the code that declares the outlook objects and the location of the email template as that works.

```vb
Sub ImportSPData() 'Source the Sharepoint data

    Dim objMyList As ListObject
    Dim objWksheet As Worksheet
    Const strSPServer As String = "https://xxxx.xxxxx.xxx.com/teams/xxxx/_vti_bin" 'Sharepoint Url
    Const LISTNAME As String = "{1574AC55-E21A-41D2-9EEC-891CFEC69BF6}" 'Sharepoint list code - where the data is inputted
    Const VIEWNAME As String = "{34D4B58A-D4C6-4190-9248-896D062543C6}" 'Sharepoint View code - The specific view of the list
    

    Set objWksheet = Worksheets("ImportData") 'Where the data is exported to
    objWksheet.Select
  
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter
    End If
    
    objWksheet.Cells.Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("A1").Select
    Set objMyList = objWksheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcExternal, Array(strSPServer, LISTNAME, VIEWNAME), False, , Range("A1")) 'where the above export lands
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Unlist
    If Not ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter
    End If

    Call applyAutoFilter 'sets up the stage. However when the "Import Data" tab is viewed, the line breaks and bullet points are missing.
    
    
End Sub

Sub Replace()
    'Populate replacement strings from sharepoint. .Range("xx") corresponds to the column containing new text.
    Dim repNumberText As String: repNumberText = dataSheet.Range("f2").Value
    Dim repTitleText As String: repTitleText = dataSheet.Range("I2").Value
    Dim repSummaryText As String: repSummaryText = dataSheet.Range("B2").Value
    Dim repImpactText As String: repImpactText = dataSheet.Range("C2").Value
    Dim repUnderwayText As String: repUnderwayText = dataSheet.Range("D2").Value
    Dim repCompletedText As String: repCompletedText = dataSheet.Range("E2").Value
    Dim repUpdateText As String: repUpdateText = dataSheet.Range("G2").Value
    
    repSummaryText = "<p>" & repSummaryText & "</p>"
    repCompletedText = "<p>" & repCompletedText & "</p>"
    
    Dim replaceStrings() As Variant
    Dim replaceWithStrings() As Variant
    'Replacement Array, replaceStrings are the text placeholders in the email templates, replacewithstrings are the variables assigned above.
    replaceStrings = Array("NumberText", "TitleText", "SummaryText", "ImpactText", "UnderwayText", "CompletedText", "UpdateText")
    replaceWithStrings = Array(repNumberText, repTitleText, repSummaryText, repImpactText, repUnderwayText, repCompletedText, repUpdateText)
    Dim currentItem As String
    Dim currentReplaceItem As String
    Dim i As Integer
    i = UBound(replaceStrings)
    Dim j As Integer
    j = 0
    
    With msgFile
        Today = Format(Now(), "DDDD DD MMM yyyy")
        'Dim HtmlBody As String
    
        'Loop through arrays and replace text
        Do Until j = i + 1
            .HtmlBody = Replace(.HtmlBody, replaceStrings(j), replaceWithStrings(j))
            j = j + 1
        Loop
    
        'Replace subject texts.\
        ' .Subject = "Communications"
        ' .Subject = Today
        .Subject = Replace(.Subject, "NumberText", repNumberText)
        .Subject = Replace(.Subject, "TitleText", repTitleText) & " " & "-" & " " & Today

        .Display
```

Comment: Is the single quote character (`"';"`) in front of the semicolon on purpose, is it a typo in your code or only in the question?

Comment: A typo, comes from retyping as I don't want to do this from my work laptop.... Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear when and where all these customizations are made. Also it is not clear where the original item comes form. Anyway, keep in mind that you need to prepare a well-formed HTML document to be able to set up the `HTMLBody` property correctly. Even if Outlook handles cases where only some tags are provided, it is better to deal with a fully-formed HTML document.

---

The Outlook object model supports three main ways of customizing the message body:

1. The [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-body-property-outlook) property returns or sets a string representing the clear-text body of the Outlook item.
2. The [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-htmlbody-property-outlook) property of the MailItem class returns or sets a string representing the HTML body of the specified item. Setting the `HTMLBody` property will always update the Body property immediately. For example:

```
     Sub CreateHTMLMail() 
       'Creates a new e-mail item and modifies its properties. 
       Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem 
       'Create e-mail item 
       Set objMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
       With objMail 
        'Set body format to HTML 
        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML 
        .HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY>Enter the message <a href="http://google.com">text</a> here. </BODY></HTML>" 
        .Display 
       End With 
     End Sub
```

3. The Word object model can be used for dealing with message bodies. See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012(v=office.12).aspx) for more information.

Note, the [MailItem.BodyFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-bodyformat-property-outlook) property allows you to programmatically change the editor that is used for the body of an item.

Comment: The source  and customisations of the data is irrelevant. You might be onto something with the object property, I will check it out and see if I can figure it out. I am not sure why the output of the debug.print .HTMLBody shows the line breaks etc. I have heard or read somewhere that later versions of outlook won't take edit HTML body and will convert it to the code it has natively. I am now looking at it from another direction that uses Ron DeBruin's excellent RangetoHTML. I fear that with what I want, it might end up being too slow.

Comment: ok, let me know whether other approaches change the picture with the message body

Comment: So, my testing and research has led me to the fact that the data is losing the formatting (Bullet points and Line breaks) between the Sharepoint list and excel. These are Multi line - enhanced rich text fields.

Comment: I have now added the code (Above) that imports the data from a sharepoint list to the spreadsheet. My suspicion is that the HTML rendering is the problem. If it is plain text, there wouldn't be the issue. However, to use bullet points, it has to be an enhanced rich text field.